# Keras model.predict() raises ValueError after load_model()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to load multiple saved keras models and use them in a separate thread of my process. I put every model in a dictionary but when I call `model.predict(data)` I get the following:

```
hub: uncaught exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mininet/ryu/ryu/lib/hub.py", line 59, in _launch
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/mininet/ryu/ryu/app/testSwitch.py", line 230, in predictor
self.predict('r1', '172.168.3.2', cnt)
File "/home/mininet/ryu/ryu/app/testSwitch.py", line 249, in predict
predictions = model.predict(counter)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/models.py", line 1027, in predict
steps=steps)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/engine/training.py", line 1797, in predict
self._make_predict_function()
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/engine/training.py", line 1009, in _make_predict_function
**kwargs)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2499, in function
return Function(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2442, in __init__
with tf.control_dependencies(self.outputs):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4304, in control_dependencies
return get_default_graph().control_dependencies(control_inputs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4017, in control_dependencies
c = self.as_graph_element(c)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3035, in as_graph_element
return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3114, in _as_graph_element_locked
raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_4/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I tried calling `model._make_predict_function()` after loading the model as suggested [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6462) but it didn't help.

**[EDIT]** The problem is probably related to multithreading, I tried to load and use multiple model in a singe process and it works smoothly.
Here's the part of the code where I use keras

```
from ryu.lib import hub
from ryu.base import app_manager

class MyClass(app_manager.RyuApp):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        ....
        self.load_models()
        self.predic_th = hub.spawn(self.predictor)
        self.another_th = hub.spawn(self.another)
        ....
    def load_models(self):
        target = [t for t in directory]
        self.models = {t:self.get_model(t) for in in target}

    def get_model(self, target):
        model = load_model('{:}_model.h5'.format(target))
        model._make_predict_function()
        return model

    def predictor(self,data, target):
        model = self.models[target]
        while True:
            model.predict(data)
            hub.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Could you share the full code?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko the full code is too long, I've added some parts of it